# Turning multiple vector layers into one raster in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, rasterization

I want to make a raster out of the multitier view I have in ArcMap 9.3.1 .

The layers in my ArcMap come from several datasets.

I know there is a 'Feature to Raster'  tool, but it converts one layer at a time.

Is there a way to convert all of the layers to a raster ( asides from export as jpg, and georeferencing the jpg) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the file menu go to export.
There you will select the jpg format and down below on the options tab you select the write world file.

[image: export jpw]